# Holder's Inequality application

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, holder-inequality

Given two sequence $\{x_{k}\}_{k\ge 1}, \{y_{k}\}_{k\ge 1},$ Holder's inequality states that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k\,y_k| \leq \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|^2 \biggr)^{\frac{1}{2}} \biggl( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |y_k|^2 \biggr)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

How we can verify that

$$\left(\sum_{k\ne l} |x_k|^2\,|x_l|^2 \right)^\frac{1}{2}\leq  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |x_k|^2 
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\sum_{k \neq l}|x_k|^{2}|x_l|^{2} \leq \sum_{k,l}|x_k|^{2}|x_l|^{2} =(\sum|x_k|^{2})^{2}$ Take square root on both sides.

[I have used the fact that $(\sum_k a_k)^{2} =\sum_{k,l} a_ka_l$].

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Could you please give a reference/proof of the hent that you have used?

Comment: Just multiply out $\sum a_k$  times itself.

Comment: OK, thanks alot!